# GridBagLayout gridwidth doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm working with the java swing LayoutManager GridBagLayout, and ran into this problem. I want a layout like this

ACC
BB

But get a layout like this

ACC
B

A and B take up the same number of columns despite B having a gridwidth of 2 where A's gridwidth is 1. I don't think there can be a vanishingly small column between A,B and C because C starts in column 1. The problem does not occur if C's gridwidth is 1 instead of 2. I'm baffled by the output.

Why is this happening / how can I fix this?

```
JFrame test = new JFrame();
test.setSize(800,800);
test.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

GridBagConstraints c;

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=0;
c.gridy=0;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
test.add(new JButton("A"), c);

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=0;
c.gridy=2;
c.gridwidth=2;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
test.add(new JButton("B"), c);

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=1;
c.gridy=0;
c.gridwidth=2;
c.gridheight=2;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 2;
c.weighty = 2;
test.add(new JButton("C"), c);

test.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know how you feel... It seems `GridBagLayout` reduces the width of columns to 0 when they are not filled by 1x1 component. I don't know if the following is the most efficient solution, but it works (by adding two dummy `JPanel` to "inflate" columns 1 and 2):

```
JFrame test = new JFrame();
test.setSize(800,800);
test.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

GridBagConstraints c;

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=0;
c.gridy=0;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
test.add(new JButton("A"), c);

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=0;
c.gridy=1;
c.gridwidth=2;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
test.add(new JButton("B"), c);

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=1;
c.gridy=0;
c.gridwidth=2;
c.gridheight=1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 2;
c.weighty = 2;
test.add(new JButton("C"), c);

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=1;
c.gridy=2;
c.gridwidth=1;
c.gridheight=0;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 0;
test.add(new JPanel(), c);

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=2;
c.gridy=3;
c.gridwidth=1;
c.gridheight=0;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.weightx = 1;
c.weighty = 0;
test.add(new JPanel(), c);

test.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You also have to set `weightx = 1; weighty = 0` if you use `gridwidth > 1`, or `weightx = 0; weighty = 1` if you use `gridheight > 1`, so the extra component does not use space. Too bad I didn't see your answer a few days ago :)

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Either add a dummy first row of a small-sized single-cell `JPanel`s or `JSeparator`s that can serve as padding *and* overcome this buggy-feature. Another alternative is to set `GridBagLayout.columnWeights` to something reasonable if you know your weights in advance (for exapmle, if you just want all your columns to have equal size), but while this workaround fixes the weight problem, it may still lead to wrong column *widths.*

This answer describes the problem with column widths, but exactly the same algorithms are applied to row heights, so if you're having trouble with multi-row components, all of the following still holds (just change `x` to `y` and widths to heights).

**The docs**

The reason behind this behavior is one real weird property of an otherwise quite flexible and useful layout manager. I don't even know whether it's a bug or a feature, because widths of columns (and, consequently, components) are determined by weights, and all the docs say about weights is

> The grid bag layout manager calculates the weight of a column to be
> the maximum weightx of all the components in a column. If the
> resulting layout is smaller horizontally than the area it needs to
> fill, the extra space is distributed to each column in proportion to
> its weight. A column that has a weight of zero receives no extra
> space.

This isn't helpful at all because it says nothing about the case when a component occupies several cells. The tutorial is a bit more “helpful”:

> Generally weights are specified with 0.0 and 1.0 as the extremes: the
> numbers in between are used as necessary. Larger numbers indicate that
> the component's row or column should get more space. For each column,
> the weight is related to the highest weightx specified for a component
> within that column, **with each multicolumn component's weight being
> split somehow between the columns the component is in.** Similarly, each
> row's weight is related to the highest weighty specified for a
> component within that row. Extra space tends to go toward the
> rightmost column and bottom row.

(Emphasis mine.)

Really? *Split somehow?* Now, *that* is really helpful.

**The actual algorithm**

The actual algorithm behind this split is really unintuitive. It iterates over all components several times. During the first pass, it only works with components that have the smallest size (in terms of cells occupied). Then it takes the next size and iterates again, until all sizes are extinguished. In your case, the component A has size 1, and the components B and C have size 2, so the order of iteration will be A, C, B. If A had size 3, then the order would be C, B, A.

During each iteration, the algorithm calculates weights for columns that the component occupies, using the following procedure.

1. Take the component weight and subtract weights of all columns it occupies, as they are calculated by this moment (including previous iterations for smaller sizes!). The resulting number is the difference between the current total weight of the columns and the weight of the component.
2. If the resulting number is zero or less, do nothing.
3. Otherwise, distribute this difference between the columns, *proportional to their current weights!*
4. If anything left of the weight difference, add these “leftovers” to the rightmost cell occupied by the component.

The actual code, for the intrigued:

```java
px = constraints.tempX + constraints.tempWidth; // tempX is gridx, tempWidth is gridwidth
weight_diff = constraints.weightx; // the weight of the component
for (k = constraints.tempX; k < px; k++) // iteration over the cells
    weight_diff -= r.weightX[k]; // r.weightX holds the current column weights
if (weight_diff > 0.0) {
    weight = 0.0;
    for (k = constraints.tempX; k < px; k++)
        weight += r.weightX[k]; // weight is the total weight of the cells
    for (k = constraints.tempX; weight > 0.0 && k < px; k++) {
        double wt = r.weightX[k];
        double dx = (wt * weight_diff) / weight; // a part of the weight
        r.weightX[k] += dx;
        weight_diff -= dx;
        weight -= wt;
    }
    /* Assign the remainder to the rightmost cell */
    r.weightX[px-1] += weight_diff;
}
```

(Some of the comments mine.)

This algorithm sounds more or less reasonable, but it has a few drawbacks.

If one of the columns has its current weight equal to zero, then it will get no weight addition at all. If *all* the columns have zero weight, then the loop won't even start and all the weight will be considered “leftovers” and go into the rightmost cell!

That's why your argument

> I don't think there can be a vanishingly small column between A,B and
> C because C starts in column 1.

doesn't really work because it's the column that `C` *ends* (not starts!) at that matters here.

**Examples**

What does this mean in your case? I assume that `gridy=2` is a typo, and `BB` should have `gridy=1` (but that doesn't really change anything because all you did was add an invisible row `1` between `0` and `2`).

1. During the first pass, only `A` is visited. It has `weightx` of `1`, and it all goes to column `0`. No surprise here. But columns `1` and `2` still have zero weights.
2. During the second pass, `CC` is visited first. It has `weightx` of `2`. It occupies columns `1` and `2`, but since they both have zero weights, all weight goes into column `2` that now has weight `2`.
3. Then `BB` is visited. It has `weightx` of `1`. It is split between columns `0` and `1`. But column `1` still has zero weight, so all of it goes into column `0`. But it already has weight `1`, so the difference between its weight and the weight of the component is zero, and nothing happens.

The resulting weights are 1-0-2, and the layout is

```
A||CC
B|| // B actually goes into the second column, but it has zero width
```

But what if `BB` had `weightx` of `2`? Then everything would be the same up to step 3, but then the difference between the weight of the component (`2`) and the current weight of column `0` (`1`) would be `1`, so that `1` would be added to the weight of column `0`, and its weight would become `2`. The weight of column `1` would still be zero, and the resulting layout would be

```
AA||CC
BB|| // B actually goes into the second column, but it has zero width
```

All three components would have the same width, but it still wouldn't look like we expect.

**The solution**

One obvious solution, mentioned in the other answer, is to add some dummy single-cell components into the first row. It will cause columns to have non-zero weights during all passes, as soon as the algorithm is done with the first row. `JSeparator` or `JPanel` works fine for this purpose. By playing around with `insets` and component's heights it is easily possible to get a nice look.

**Another possible solution**

If you know your column weights in advance, you can simply override the whole algorithm and simply provide the right weights by

```java
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
layout.columnWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
test.setLayout(layout);
```

Adjust the weights accordingly if you need your columns to have different weights. The problem with this approach, however, that a somewhat similar algorithm is applied to calculate the column *widths* (as opposed to weights). In particular, if, at some moment, a component is found to require more width than the total width of the column the component occupies, then the width *difference* is spread among *all* columns.

This means that if, for example, a component that needs 150 pixels wants to occupy two columns that have current widths of 0 and 50, then the difference (100) is split between the columns evenly, resulting in a 50/100 split instead of 75/75 as one would expect. The solution is to either switch to the fake first row solution or to set column widths directly in the same manner as `columnWeights` (by setting `GridBagLayout.columnWidths`). This, of course, requires a bit more complicated calculations than widths.